# Control order of token filters in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, tokenize

Trying to control the order that token filters are applied in ElasticSearch.

I know from the docs that the tokenizer is applied first, then the token filters, but they do not mention how the order of the token filters is determined.

Here's a YAML snippet from my analysis setup script:

```
       KeywordNameIndexAnalyzer :
           type : custom
           tokenizer : whitespace
           filter : [my_word_concatenator, keyword_ngram]
```

I would have thought that `my_word_concatenator` would be applied before `keyword_ngram`, but it seems like that isn't the case.  Anyone know how (or if) the order of these filters can be controlled?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your expectations are correct. The filters in the [custom analyzer](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/a0a8538ef9c7d8f24dc9b9f081c548f7d9e8b7cd/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/CustomAnalyzer.java#L98) are applied in the order specified by the filter array.  Could you provide an example, where this doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: You are right -- the reason the order seemed off was because I used a nonsensical combination of tokenizer and token filters.  If you're curious, my_word_concatenator strips whitespace, but since I was using the whitespace tokenizer, there was no whitespace in the tokens that got to the filters.  So 1 wasn't happening at all, as opposed to happening after 2.

Comment: This is better documented in the [custom analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html) section.
so yea order does matter in your case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An analyzer is made of a tokenizer, which splits your text into tokens. After that token filters come into the picture, in the order you configured them, since you're providing an array. If you have doubts I'd suggest you to have a look at the [analyze api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html), through which you can actually test how a analyzer works without indexing any text.